# checkbox bug - any help?

Tags: gui, gtk, button, checkbox

After a fresh install, I installed some `gtk3` themes and change the icon settings, resulting this checkbox bug.

Is there a way to solve this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, I don't why and how but I placed yaru-teal-dark to .themes and yaru-teal to .icons folder. Then this bug occur, the original content I downloaded from gnome-look zip file included yaru-teal yaru-teal-dark yaru-teal-light folders I placed the other two to .themes folder then the bug disappeared.